# In Jenkins, is it possible to have parameter selection with categories?

Tags: jenkins

I wanted to have a job, in which the user can select parameters that are displayed in categories like a tree. This is similar to the extended choice plugin but with split up.

Example:

```
DMM
- XDMM
- YDMM 
SMU
- XSMU
- YSMU
```

[Sample UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOtak.png)

In the above example, user should be able to select one or many options among XDMM, YDMM, XSMU, YSMU.

It will be good if the user can expand and collapse the DMM and SMU categories.

I explored the extended choice plugin, but there is no option to have categories.
I also tried using the Active choice plugin for the top category (DMM, SMU) and Active choice reactive plugin referenced to the previous Active choice plugin for subcategories (XDMM, YDMM, XSMU, YSMU).

But the issue in this is, I select DMM, select XDMM and then switch to SMU and select XSMU. In this case, XDMM will not be present in parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter) should allow you to do this.

Comment: @sree, did you try the suggested plugin; did it work?